# Check the bit of a char

Tags: c, byte, shift

I am trying to check one specific bit of a char, for example one emoji '' on the first octet we have '11110xxx' and I need to check if the 3 bit its 0, but I don't know what to do!

I get some code from the internet like:

```
printf( "%d", ( buffer[0] >> 3 ) & 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

And it works, but I tried this:

```
printf("%d", (buffer[0] >> 3) & 1);
```

And works to, but without the `& 1` doesn't:
So I am wondering for what its the:

```
? 1 : 0 //Works without
```

and the `& 1` that its need for working

Another thing its, with that I shifted from right to left or left to right? I tried this:

```
printf("%d", (buffer[0] << 3) & 1);
```

But doesn't work.

I am trying to learn how to work with the bytes

Comment: `( buffer[0] >> 3 ) & 1` will only ever return `1` or `0`, so the ternary operator in this case is not needed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thats what I need, because he always return 1 or 0 with that

Comment: Using `!!` (two logical NOT operator) is another way to return `1` for true and `0` for false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`? 1 : 0` is a latter half of ternary operator. Writing `A ? B : C`, `B` is evaluated when `A` is true (non-zero) and `C` is evaluated when `A` is false (zero).

`& 1` is bitwise AND operator and one. It is extracting the last bit (LSB) by using by taking AND with one.

If you want to use right to left shift, you can apply that to `1`.

```
printf("%d", buffer[0] & (1 << 3) ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: So if I dont use the '? 1 : 0' its ok because, I dont need to replace the statement with the ternary operator

Comment: if I want to shift from right to left I dont need to use `buffer[0] & (1 << 5) ? 1 : 0)`, because I want the 3 bit? If I go from left to right its the 3rd but if I go from right to the left becomes the 5th

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> And works to, but without the & 1 doesn't.

Because `& 1` sets all bits except the lower one to zero. Example: `0xff >> 3 == 0x1f` and `(0xff >> 3) & 1 == 1`.

2.

> Another thing its, with that I shifted from right to left or left to
> right? I tried this:
>
> ```
> printf("%d", (buffer[0] << 3) & 1);
> ```

When you shift left the lowest bits are set to zero. So the result of `& 1` will be always zero (as explained in point 1).

Generally, if you want to check if the n'th bit is set you can:

```
(val >> n) & 1
```

`val & (1 << n)` - if used in if the logical statement or if you need the value to be `zero` or `one`: `!!(val & (1 << n))` or `val & (1 << n) ? 1 : 0` or `(val & (1 << n)) >> n`